# WCF: Simple async request and response example

Tags: c#, wcf

I've been trying to learn WCF and I made hello world service to query a value and return the result. I made a client for the service (windows phone) to send a value to the server and show the result. Although I'm trying to return string in my web service, the return type of the method in the windows phone app was void and it was also async.

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetName(String PhoneNumber)
    {
        DBEntities Context = new DBEntities();
        String Name = (from x in Context.Contacts
                       where x.Number.Equals(PhoneNumber)
                       selectx.Name).FirstOrDefault();
        return Name;
    }
 ...
}
```

In client:

```
private void Submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ServiceReference1.Service1Client vv = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
    vv.GetNameAsync(TextBox1.Text);
}
```

My question is that, how can I get response from the async method ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WCF Asynchronous operations can be implemented by using one of the three following methods:

1. The task-based asynchronous pattern
2. The event-based asynchronous pattern
3. The IAsyncResult asynchronous pattern

So how to write the client code, it depends on how your implement the WCF service.The task-based asynchronous pattern is the preferred way to implement asynchronous operations because it is the easiest and most straight forward.

If use task, client code could be like this:

```
    Task<T> results = await vv.GetNameAsync(TextBox1.Text);
    T result = results.Result;
    if (result.Success)
    {
       // Do something with result
    }
```

You also need make the WCF service async, this MSDN article [How to: Implement an Asynchronous Service Operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177(v=vs.110).aspx) has a good example.

Please read [Synchronous and Asynchronous Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734701(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.